# Trying to Place Order- nothing shows up on screen

Tags: java, swing

Trying to Place Order nothing shows up on screen but I want to show a textarea saying:

> Here's Sandwhich with the topping u provided

Can you help me?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




    public void setCheese(String s) {
        cheese = s;
    }
    public String getCheese() {
        return cheese;
    }}
```

Comment: Android ain't got swing, so this don't mean a thing!

Comment: Please explain what you were trying to do! If you only put the error message it may not attract viewers and solvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be getting a NullPointerException makeASandwih as sandwich is null, then you try and call an instance method

```
protected void makeASandwich() {
    Sandwich sandwich = null;
    sandwich.setCheese(jcbcheese.getItemAt(jcbcheese.getSelectedIndex()));
```

Try creating a new instance of Sandwich

```
protected void makeASandwich() {
    Sandwich sandwich = new Sandwich();
    sandwich.setCheese(jcbcheese.getItemAt(jcbcheese.getSelectedIndex()));
```

Comment: i meant is When I confirm the order (via a place order button), IT SHOULD display a message in a textarealisting the ingredients that went into the sub. so it should print out something like THIS IS YOUR SUB: HAM,BACON,LETTUCE,ONION

Comment: Instead of displaying a `JOptionPane` which you've done?

Comment: i used something like this: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Order);

Comment: @user2879561 enjoy your lucky day, Mad doing _your_ homework for you ;-)